# Display org-todo-list of entries with deadlines?

Tags: org-mode, todo

Is there a way to get a list of org-mode entries with deadlines?  Ideally with the deadlines displayed and ordered by deadline.

I haven't found anything like this. The closest thing I find is `org-check-deadlines`, which just let's me know about things that are due in the next fortnight or are already overdue.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thead that suggests using the built-in agenda colums / table view:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12364/show-timestamp-for-each-todo-in-org-agenda-global-todo-list

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways to do this using [agenda views](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html#Agenda-Views).  The simplest is to use the week agenda: `C-a a a`.  This will display the items in `org-agenda-files` that have timestamps within the current week, as well as deadlines due in the next 14 days (or whatever the value of `org-deadline-warning-days` is).

You can also use the built-in [searching](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html) tools to do this (`C-c a m`).  Just check the `DEADLINE` property. A search for `DEADLINE>="<today>"` will return entries with deadlines of today or later and `DEADLINE<"<today>"` returns overdue deadlines.  You can save the search in a `tags` [custom view](http://orgmode.org/manual/Storing-searches.html#Storing-searches) in `org-agenda-custom-commands` if you plan to use it a lot.  For example:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
      '("D" "Deadlines"
        tags "DEADLINE>=\"<today>\""))
```

Finally, you can make an agenda view that shows *only* deadlines by setting `org-agenda-entry-types`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("A" "Agenda; only deadlines"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline)))
               ))
```

To display the deadline, the easiest way is to use [columns](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-view.html#Column-view).  There is an example in the [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12364/show-timestamp-for-each-todo-in-org-agenda-global-todo-list) @lawlist linked to in their comment.

Comment: Both of those seem useful.  Two questions, or 3, rather:

(1) Can `(setq org-columns-default-format)` be specified for a specific agenda view?

(2) When I get the agenda view in columns using `DEADLINE>=\"<today>\""`, it's actually sorted by most distant rather than most recent. Is there a way to specify within the custom command how the first column should sort?

(3) For the last method you mention, is there any way to make it default to "month view" rather than "week view"?

Comment: You can use `org-agenda-overriding-columns-format` to change the columns in a specific agenda view and `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` to change the sort method.  The time span (in days) of the agenda is controlled by `org-agenda-span`

Comment: I can't quite get it.  I've made: (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
      `'("Z" "Deadlines"
        tags "DEADLINE>=\"<today>\""
 ((org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%DEADLINE %75ITEM")(org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-up))(org-agenda-view-columns-initially t))
 ))`

but it doesn't seem to get the sorting right.

Comment: **Some** sorting cannot be accomplished because text-properties are missing in the original source code -- i.e., grep for `org-add-props txt props` and examine the text properties of the *applicable* functions used to gather the data.  `org-entries-lessp` relies upon those hidden text properties to sort by the `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`.  This is a new question, which would require rewriting some of the basic functions -- most people are hesitant to touch the source code by modifying lengthy functions -- it is a holy/sacred issue for most users :) .  It cannot be fixed with a simple advice.

Comment: @lawlist Have you considered submitting a patch or bug report for this? I've also had this sorting problem.

Comment: I just sent an email to the org-mode team -- `emacs-orgmode@gnu.org` -- suggesting that some attention be given to the nine (9) locations where `org-add-props txt props` is used -- i.e., that an effort be made to calculate values and add text properties for all sorting types of the `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`, so that `org-entries-lessp` can do its job better.  I didn't receive a tracking number, so I'm not sure whether it will actually receive any attention.