# Editing and viewing timestamps in Global TODO in Org Agenda

Tags: org-agenda, todo, org-super-agenda

When viewing alltodo's (M-x org-agenda RET t), is it possible to see and edit Scheduled/Due dates?

I understand that the list of TODOs can be very long and therefore seeing timestamps could clutter up the view. However, I am using [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda/blob/master/examples.org) to drastically trim down my list of TODOs. Being able to see and edit timestamps could significantly improve workflow.

A [closely-related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12393/25547) was discussed 4 years ago. I could configure column-view to see timestamps, but that doesn't solve the need to edit in-place.

Comment: for now, I am going to use 'F' (follow mode) to at least display the task's information as I scroll my list. I still have to switch windows in order to edit. Too bad a lot of the ability to edit tasks is missing in todo-type agenda buffers. (how does one make feature suggestions to org developers?)

Comment: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html  "*You can submit feature requests – Org is already mature, but new ideas keep popping up. If you want to request a feature, it might be a good idea to have a look at the current Issue tracking file which captures both bug reports and feature requests. Or dig into the mailing list for possible previous discussions about your idea. If you cannot find back your idea, formulate it as detailed as possible, if possible with examples, and send it to the mailing list.*"  https://orgmode.org/manual/Feedback.html -- emacs-orgmode@gnu.org