# How to add a timestamp directly from the 'todo'-type agenda buffer

Tags: org-agenda, todo, org-super-agenda

My typical agenda view is a global todo agenda. I would like to add timestamps directly to a header from this view. It is possible with deadline and schedule but not for timestamps.

I have tried the org-agenda-date-prompt command but get the following error:
"Not allowed in 'todo'-type agenda buffer or component"

Searching I found other people with the same issue [Editing and viewing timestamps in Global TODO in Org Agenda](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54230/editing-and-viewing-timestamps-in-global-todo-in-org-agenda). That is 4 years sine that question was posted. Are there any news of such a feature? And if not, could it be possible to implement for an emacs newcomer to implement it?

Comment: So this is a duplicate question for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54230/. Please delete it. Just because there is no acceptable answer or a question is old, that doesn't mean that you should post a duplicate question. You can instead add a comment on that question, asking for updates or whatever.

Comment: AFAICT, it's not the same question: the linked question asks about displaying timestamp information in the TODO agenda and possibly editing it from that view. This one is about adding plain timestamps to an entry from that view. The answer to this one is that it is possible through a remote editing command,(see [Commands in the agenda buffer](https://orgmode.org/guide/Agenda-Commands.html) ) but although there are such editing commands for SCHEDULED and DEADLINE timestamps, there is no such function for plain timestamps - but it should not be too difficult to implement one.

Comment: The answer to the linked question is "no, you cannot view timestamp information in the agenda (unless the timestamp is part of the headline)", so although you can technically edit a SCHEDULED or DEADLINE timestamp, you'd be doing it blind: the only editing that makes sense is a complete replacement - AFAIK of course.

Comment: @Drew I am unable to add a comment on that question, since I do not have the required reputation.

Comment: @NickD Thanks, I'll try to look into it. If I end up successfully implementing it, I'll post it here. It is possible to show timestamps in the agenda, but it requires you to be in column-view. That is fine for me.